# Adding python script to Scheduled Task

Tags: python, task, scheduler

I'm trying to add a python script to Scheduled Task in Windows.
There are 2 ways and none of it doesnt work.
**First solution:**
added to a batch file the call of my python script

```
python.exe hello_world.py
```

in the Scheduled task - Program\script - the path to this bat file. No argument and "start in"

**Second solution:**
In the Task Scheduler - Program\script - added the path to python.exe. The Arguments field - path to my py file.

hello_world.py does this (writes in the main.log file info)

```
from base_logger import logging
logging.info('Starting hello world')
```

When i run both task scheduled solutions, my main.log is still empty, so i'm deductiong that py script is'nt running.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont forget to check access rights to folder where you're py script is located.